# Template specific subscriptions in an array

Tags: meteor

```
Template.recent.created = function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscriptions = [
      this.subscribe('users'),
      this.subscribe('posts'),
      this.subscribe('comments')
    ];
  }.bind(this));
};

Template.recent.rendered = function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    var allReady = _.every(this.subscriptions, function (subscription) {
      return subscription.ready();
    });
    ...
```

Is this the correct way to subscribe to more than one DB source in a template? When I render this template again while it's still loading, then it seems to go into infinite loading state.

Related doc: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Comment: Did my answer helped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to wrap your subscriptions in a `Tracker.autorun`. In fact, each sub has a `onReady` callback that you can use:

```
this.subscribe('subName', {onReady: function() {
  //Do something when ready
}});
```

But besides that, there is a `subscriptionsReady()` function that returns `true` when all your template subs are ready ([see the doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun)):

So your code become:

```
Template.recent.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscriptions = [
    this.subscribe('users'),
    this.subscribe('posts'),
    this.subscribe('comments')
  ];

  if(this.subscriptionsReady()) {
    //do something when all subs are ready
  }
});
```

And in your template you can also check if all template's subs are ready:

```
<template name="templateName">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    Everything is ready!
  {{else}}
    Loading...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```